# Is it possible to add specific files uncompressed to a Android APK using build.xml?

Tags: android

Does anyone know if its possible to add specific files uncompressed to a Android APK file during the ANT build process using build.xml? All my files live in the *assets* folder and use the same extension. I do realise that i could use a different extension for the files that i don't want to be added compressed and specify, for example:

```
<nocompress extension="NoCompress" />
```

but this currently isn't an option for me.

I tried adding my own *aapt add* step after the *appt package* step in the *package-resource* section in *build.xml*:

```
<exec executable="${aapt}" taskName="add">
<arg value="add" />
<arg value="-v" />
<arg value="${out.absolute.dir}/TestAndroid.ap_" />
<arg value="${asset.absolute.dir}/notcompressed.and" />
</exec>
```

Which did add the file to the APK but it was compressed. :)

Is this possible or is a different extension the only way?

Thanks!

Comment: For the benefit of other Android Gradle devs who come here: `android { aaptOptions { noCompress 'foo', 'bar' } }`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/)

> The only way (that I’ve discovered, as of this writing) to control
>   this behavior is by using the -0 (zero) flag to aapt on the command
>   line. This flag, passed without any accompanying argument, will tell
>   aapt to disable compression for all types of assets. Typically you
>   will not want to use this exact option, because for most assets,
>   compression is a desirable thing. Sometimes, however, you will have a
>   specific type of asset (say, a database), that you do not want to
>   apply compression to. In this case, you have two options.
>
> First, you can give your asset file an extension in the list above.
>   While this does not necessarily make sense, it can be an easy
>   workaround if you don’t want to deal with aapt on the command line.
>   The other option is to pass a specific extension to the -0 flag, such
>   as -0 db, to disable compression for assets with that extension. You
>   can pass the -0 flag multiple times, and each time with a separate
>   extension, if you need more than one type to be uncompressed.
>
> Currently, there is no way to pass these extra flags to aapt when
>   using the ADT within Eclipse, so if you don’t want to sacrifice the
>   ease of use of the GUI tools, you will have to go with the first
>   option, and rename your file’s extension.

Comment: Thanks for the response vasart. The link you posted discusses controlling compression through file extensions and is something i'm able to do, however, as mentioned in my question, this method currently isn't available to me. The -0 option isn't available for the aapt add command. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 2):

If building using gradle, then it seems you can provide the aapt flags like this:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'foo', 'bar'
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }
}
```

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-aapt-options

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide closure for this one.

I don't think it is possible to mark individual files to be added uncompressed to the APK.

Being able to mark individual files as uncompressed to *aapt* could be useful. As would the addition of a *nocompress file* tag, eg:

```
<nocompress file="FileNoCompress.abc" />
```

:)