# Maximum size of Video can be add in raw folder android supported?

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I have 70MB video file and i want to play through raw folder but app is not launching
how to add this video file in asset/raw folder in android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its quite clear from Documentation that your apk size can be uptu **4 GB**. So there will be now issue to keep one 70 MB file inside raw folder. See [Android Break Limitation of 50 MB](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html)

APK size depends largely on *draw able, Assets and Raw* folder

**Issue  :**
Generally bigger size of apk does not installed on device or they create issue while installing.

**If you are compelled and do not have server then keep it inside raw else keep video at server download it once application run first time save in Local Memory**

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But My Requirement is to store video in raw folder not on Server so when running application it is giving In Sufficient Storage please suggest me.

Comment: you can set android:installLocation="preferExternal" inside Manifest

Answer (score 5):

The size limit is 1MB. (although I havent found this in android docs but found this info from several other links). So better to split you video in different raw files which size will be less than 1MB and use from them.

Also remember that  you can not upload an apk which size is more than 50mb in google play. So if you want that you will need apk expansion files too.

Helpful Links

1. [link1](http://blog.rossgreenhalf.com/2010/12/13/android-file-size-limits/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563373/the-reason-for-assets-and-raw-resources-in-android)