# Can there be a content directory, where I can put files (compile time) and load files from (run time), inside an app?

Tags: android

I have some image files which will be dynamically loaded in my app. I know I can put images in the "/res/drawable" directory, but can there be somewhere else I can put files and loaded them by file name at runtime?

The image files contain characters that are now allowed in resource names. I did not name them, so ideally, I need to keep the names. For example, suppose I have "Cat #1.png" and "Cat #2.png", and I would like to load the image into an ImageView by that name at runtime, like so:

```
MyImageView1.setImageBitmap(createBitmapFromContentDirectory("Cat Pictures/Cat #2.png"))
MyImageView2.setImageBitmap(createBitmapFromContentDirectory("Dog Pictures/Dog #1.png"))
```

Is that possible, or should I change all image names into conforming names (e.g., cat_number1.png and cat_number2.png) and put them into the drawable directory?

Comment: are you aware of assets directory?

Comment: I might have, but I did not remember it when posting this. Thank you for the hint. I think 'assets' is the correct solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put them in assets & load them from there,
Otherwise you can also put them in raw folder. 
you can refer to [Where do I I Place assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio) for assets.assets doesn't create Resource Id, so you can access them directly. Have a look at this
[difference between assets & raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563373/the-reason-for-assets-and-raw-resources-in-android).