# Should an extra file be placed in raw or assets folder?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app project. It contains a file which contains a JSON. One can use it to mock the API call response during the development of the application.

Should I place that file in the `raw` folder or in the `assets` folder in the project?

If you answer, kindly provide reasoning behind it as well.

Comment: I store my JSON file in `assets`. You can check out the difference between them here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/9563467/5444161]

Comment: Whichever is appropriate. I'd prefer assets in that case, but it's entirely up to you

Comment: I'd use `assets` for a group of related things (say help files in different languages) or a font. I'd use `raw` for something unique (a set of sounds, for instance).

Comment: I think this question is opinion based.

Comment: @Gaurav If preference between 2 things is just opinion based, then it literally means both things are subjectively equal, and hence preferring one over the other is purely subjective. Why would Android keep 2 different distinct folders for doing the exact same thing? Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assets/` is flexible in terms of structure. You can have your own directory tree in there, for organizing lots of files.

`res/raw/` is flexible in terms of resource sets. You can have different versions of that resource for different configurations (e.g., `res/raw/` as the default, `res/raw-zh/` for use on devices configured for Chinese language use).

If you do not need any of those features, `assets/` and `res/raw/` are about equal in terms of capability. I tend to default to `assets/`.

Comment: perfect answer. Thanks!