# How to scale and save View to SDCard

Tags: android, view, scale

I have one `View` now I am trying to save it as fix size for example `500*666` into sdcard. Image save successfully but Image save as following. Image is save as on corner of entire image Please see attached image.

Code :

```
 private void onSave(final View v) {
 v.setMinimumWidth(500);
        v.setMinimumHeight(666);
Bitmap viewBitmap_save = null;

                            savingdialog();
                            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
                            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(
                                    dm);
                            Display display = getWindowManager()
                                    .getDefaultDisplay();

                            viewBitmap_save = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 666,
                                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);// i
                            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap_save);
                            v.draw(canvas);
                            try {
                                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                                long RANDOMFILENUMBER = randomGenerator
                                        .nextLong();
                                File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                                        "/sdcard/Image Telling/");
                                // have the object build the directory
                                // structure, if needed.
                                wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
                                // create a File object for the output file

                                // FileOutputStream outStream = new
                                // FileOutputStream(file);
                                File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory,
                                        RANDOMFILENUMBER + ".png");
                                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(
                                        outputFile);
                                viewBitmap_save.compress(CompressFormat.PNG,
                                        100, outStream);

                                sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                                        Uri.parse("file://"
                                                + Environment
                                                        .getExternalStorageDirectory())));

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
}
```

I am giving width and hight as fix because i need image as fixed size. How to scale View ?? Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion.

Do not give any height,width to view and then *get Bitmap of Original View* as you are getting.

Once you got bitmap created from view, then apply scaling.. you may use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`

And then save that scaled bitmap.

Comment: actually i am using viewflipper which have different childs now when user click on save button I want to save current child from view flipper

View viewtosave = vf_letters.getCurrentView();
it give me current view of ViewFlipper
which i am trying to save.

Comment: Have you tried as I said before commenting?....  "create Bitmap of tha viewtosave..without giving height width.. once a bitmap created then scale it down".

Comment: Yes I try with it. I remove 
 v.setMinimumWidth(500); and v.setMinimumHeight(666); and create bitmap. But How to scale it to fix size that is 500*666 ?

Comment: Then before writing it to sdcard.. scale it..like.. `b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 500, 660, true);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to refer these links may be you will get output as you need.

- [Android: high quality image resizing / scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207562/android-high-quality-image-resizing-scaling)
- [Android image scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126654/android-image-scaling)
- http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/scale-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html

Try it once

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am facing problem : "Image is display as upper left corner of entire view". Not in scale image.